# upload file without redirecting or refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, knockout.js

how can i upload an image to a folder without refreshing or redirecting to a new page? i was thinking of using php5 from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp what i want to do is a page where the user can upload their own photos without refreshing the page or redirecting i will have all the images that the user uploaded previously in that same page the user will them be able to choose from any of their own images and insert them inside a draggable.

```js
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function(e) {
  /** Make div draggable **/
  $('<div />', {
    class: 'ui-widget-content',
    appendTo: '.container',
    draggable: {
      containment: 'parent',
      start: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
      }
    }
  });
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function() {
  return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function() {
  var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
  if (editingText.length) {
    editingText.hide();
    editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
  }
});


var count = 1;
var selectedDraggable;

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable = {

  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    $(element).draggable();
    $(element).addClass('item' + count);
    count++;
    $(element).on('click', function() {
      selectedDraggable = $(this);
    })
  }
};


var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray();
  self.textContent = ko.observable('');
  self.init = function() {
    self.items([]);
  }
  self.remove = function(item) {
    console.log(item);
    self.items.remove(item);
  }
  self.addNew = function() {
    self.items.push(self.textContent());
    self.textContent('');
  }
  self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```css
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* unvisited link */

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* visited link */

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* mouse over link */

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* selected link */

</style><style>.toolbar {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 490px;
  height: 23px;
  border: none;
  position: none;
}
</style> <style>.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
}
.edit_text {
  display: none;
}
.fix_backround {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.container {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
  <p align="center">
    <textarea data-bind="value: textContent" Placeholder="Type text to append" rows="4" cols="21"></textarea>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button data-bind="click: addNew">Create</button>
  </p>


  <p align="center">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  </p>


  <center>
    <div class="container">
      <div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
        <div href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
          <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span>
            <input class="edit_text" />
          </center>
          <?php include( 'fig.php'); $query_image="SELECT * FROM empleo_work order by id desc limit 1" ; // This query will show you all images if you want to see only one image pass id='$id' e.g. "SELECT * FROM nametable id='$id'". $result=m ysql_query($query_image);
          if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) { while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo'
          <br>
          <br>
          <a href="upload1/'.$row[" images "].'">
            <img src="upload1/'.$row[" images "].'" style=w idth="165" height="104">
          </a>
          '; } } else { echo 'File name not found in database'; } ?></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>

</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script>
<script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Do a web search for `ajax upload`. Lots of existing scripts to simplify process or information on how to do it yourself

Comment: Get rid of the form and do the upload via AJAX. If you want to keep the form, tap into the form's `submit` event and call `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function previewFile(vid,iid) {

  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var preview = document.querySelector(vid);
  
  var file    = document.querySelector(iid).files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    $(vid).show();
    
    /*** Write your code for image upload here***/
    
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="img_file" id="img_file" onchange="previewFile('#img_upload','#img_file')"/>

<img src="../img/no-logo.gif" id="img_upload" alt="Image">
```